# Grouping 2 different columns in a .csv

Tags: r, grouping

I have a .csv file with 2 colums.

Gender and Age,

I am trying to group how many Males age 80 and over, how many Males between 60-79...etc.  Is there a way to do that?  I can group by just one column, but I cant seem to find a way to do it with two.  If you have a place to for me to go look it up that would be great.

```
male_group <- vector(mode="character", length=length(data$gender))

male_group[data$gender,data$age>= Male & 80] <- "80 and Over"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the which(). For instance, I suggest following command for the query of "how many Males age 80 and over?".

```
male_group[which(data$gender=='Male' & data$age>=80),] <- "80 and Over"
```

I assumed you managed to import your .csv file with GUI or commands like read.csv()

Regards,

Reza Sadeghi

Comment: If you need further help, please share some sample data.

Comment: Thank you I will look into the which command.  Yes I was able to import my .csv file.